# how to use a dependency of multiple major versions in npm 7 workspaces

Tags: npm, workspace, monorepo, npm-workspaces

I have an NPM 7.0 workspaces monorepo.

Several of the sub-packages use different major versions of a dependency.

However, it seems like NPM workspaces is only able to install a single version and has issues serving me the correct major version when I use the dependency in one of the packages.

In YARN I could add the dependency to `noHoist`, but this doesn't seem to exist or work in NPM 7.0 workspaces.

Comment: I would be interested in having a minimal example

Comment: @abernier this is the repo http://github.com/CyCraft/magnetar I'm trying to use with npm 7 workspaces. As soon as you clean all package-locks and convert it to npm 7 workspaces: Multiple versions of Vue give issues when you try to open the dev server with `npm run dev:vue2`, it still tries to use version 3.

Comment: Hi @mesqueeb Did you solve this problem?